# Tomcat : 404 The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, tomcat

I am using hibernate framework. Here is the hibernate.cfg.xml file code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">702711</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.69.18.24:1521:xe</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">system</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

  <mapping class="com.eccSports.entity.UserEntity"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And the web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>ECCSports</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.eccSports.api</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[This is the directory structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MByO.png)

All the files are there but I am still getting 404. I restarted server several times, but still its not working.

Comment: Why you are relating this to hibernate? Which MVC you are using?

Comment: @vipincp Basically I am working on some angular stuff and connecting my oracle database through hibernate.

Comment: And how does your request look like? anything in the logs?

Comment: @piet.t which log?

Comment: Tomcat's server log, stdout, your application logs - you name it.

Comment: What URL are you requesting? What do you expect to handle that URL? What context path is your application deployed to?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are useing jersey and hibernate .... make sure you are following the below given steps ...

1. Whatever url you are sending it must contain your given url pattern : `<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>`

   eg:
        http://localhost:8080/yourpath/api/classlevelurl/
2. Make sure that service you are writing is inside com.eccSports.api package. as you have mentioned in web.xml

Comment: Yes that I have checked. But even the index file is not loading

Comment: check out path in your tomcat server.xml